# My function will log a value to the console, but it won't return the same value - why?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, recursion

I've created the following function to flatten a nested array:

```
function steamroller(arr) {

  arr = arr.reduce(function(a, b, i){
    return a.concat(b); 
    },[]);

  if (!Array.isArray(arr[arr.length-1])) {console.log(arr); return arr;}

  steamroller(arr); 
}

steamroller([1, [2], [3, [[4]]]]);
```

The code will log a nicely flattened array to the console, but the function returns 'undefined'.

I'm stumped - why is this?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a return when calling `steamroller` recursively. Fixed code:

```
function steamroller(arr) {

  arr = arr.reduce(function(a, b, i){
    return a.concat(b); 
    },[]);

  if (!Array.isArray(arr[arr.length-1])) {console.log(arr); return arr;}

  return steamroller(arr); 
}

steamroller([1, [2], [3, [[4]]]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me even without return (Firefox)

[image]

Comment: It's "working" for you because of the console log statement in the fifth line, which the OP says is working fine.

Comment: If I do alert(steamroller([1, [2], [3, [[4]]]])); I also see the same output in the alert. That is indicator that the steamroller method is returnig the same value as console.log.